# SharedPreferences same value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I've just a quick question regarding sharedPreferences: It seems that all my Keys gets overwritten by the last value:

**SessionManagement.class**

```
public class SessionManagement {

SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context _context;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "UserSession";
public static final String KEY_1 = "0";
public static final String KEY_2 = "0";

public SessionManagement(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void SaveValues(String value, String fragment){
    if(fragment == "fragment1"){
        editor.putString(KEY_1, value).commit();
    }

    if(fragment == "fragment2"){
        editor.putString(KEY_2, value).commit();
    }
}

public String getValues(String fragment){
    String value = "";

    if(fragment == "fragment1"){
        value = pref.getString(KEY_1, "");
    }

    if(fragment == "fragment2"){
        value = pref.getString(KEY_2, "");
    }

    return value;
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
SessionManagement session;

session = new SessionManagement(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

//Save Values
session.SaveValues("1","fragment1");
session.SaveValues("2","fragment2");

//Read Values
tv_temp.setText(session.getValues("fragment1") + ", " + 
session.getValues("fragment2"));
```

My expected output would look like this: 1, 2

But it seems that the first key gets overwritten by the second key so my output looks like this: 2, 2

*Is there anything I have to change within my functions so I get the correct output (1, 2)?*

BR

Comment: String comparison is made with `equals` not `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two keys have the same value (i.e `"0"`). Try to change one of them and your problem should be fixed. :)

Comment: In addition to this, you should use `.equals()` for string comparison instead of  `==`.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake. Take a look in the values that you defined for `KEU_1` and  `KEY_2`, they have the same value. Replace it with the values below:

```
public static final String KEY_1 = "0";
public static final String KEY_2 = "1";
```